# custom-sort for b-table-column

Tags: javascript, html, buefy

I have a b-table-column which contains both files and folders in it differentiate by props.row.itemtype as 'files' or 'folders. I want to sort this column so that the files and folders are grouped separately.

I read something about custom-sort property of buefy but could not get much knowledge about it.

Can anyone help me out with implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a compare function using the typical a, b arguments where you do your comparing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

In addition Buefy passes a 3rd argument to indicate if it's ascending (as the same function id used for toggling sort direction).

Sample:

```
/**
 * Custom sort
 */
sortByCustom(a, b, isAsc) {
  return isAsc
          ? a.localeCompare(b)
          : b.localeCompare(a)
}
```